# Create a file from an OutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I have this problem that I am creating a file but this is creating empty file.

I am using a API of Dropbox, Code of Dropbox operate good, but I don't Know that I don't fine. I have used 2º and 3º Codes for my app, this is operating good.

This operate by hierarchically. I am sending outputStream for the fuction. But this is empty.

I am using outputStream because I need that this operates with outputstream.

1º Code(Class Test || Call):

```
File tempFile=new File("C:\\PRUEBAS_TFG\\cloud.png"); if ( ! tempFile.exists() ) { tempFile.createNewFile(); } 
File file = new File("C:\\PRUEBAS_TFG\\cloud.png");
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
catmanager.downloadFilesToItem(catmanager.getAllListCatalog().get(0), catmanager.getAllListCatalog().get(0).getItems().get(2), listFile, outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

2º Code(Class catmanager || 1ºbody):

```
public void downloadFilesToItem(Catalog catalog, Item item, List<String> files, OutputStream output){
    try{
        String fsPath;
        fsPath = pathCatalog(catalog);
        getFSManager().changeDirectoryConfigNPath(fsPath+"/"+item.getName()+"_item");
        for(int i = 0;i<files.size();i++){
            getFSManager().downloadFile(files.get(i), output);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

3ºCode(Class FSManager || 2ºbody)

```
public void downloadFile(String fileName, OutputStream output) throws IOException{//Aqui deveria Buscar el Fichero Funciona por que da la casualidad que esta el fichero en la primera nube 
    /** Cogemos la lista de FS del usuario */
    List<IFileSystem> aux = getFileSystemsUser();

    for(int i = 0; i < aux.size();i++){
        /** Se realiza la Funcionalidad del metodo*/
        System.out.println(aux.get(i).toString());
        try{
            aux.get(i).downloadFile(_listPath.get(i)+"/"+fileName, output);
            i = aux.size()+1;
        }catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

4ºCode(Class aux Dropbox || API Dropbox):

```
public void downloadFile(String fileName, OutputStream aux) throws IOException{
    try{
        getDbxClient().getFile(fileName, null, aux);
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw e;
    }catch(DbxException u){
        throw new IOException(u.getCause());
    }
}
```

Thanks Advance.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal (and better formatted) example, please? :-) We’d be gald to help. :-)

Comment: thanks for the advice , I have modified the post

Answer (score 1):

You are using one `FileOutputStream` for downloading a list of file. Do you expect to merge the files (in one image), or something like that?

If is is not expected, I certainly would not pass the `FileOutputStream` as input parameter of your successive calls (2,3,4), but an instance of `File` representing the folder. In your last method (4), create (and close after download) a new FileOutputStream for a file in that folder. Something like

```
public void downloadFile(String fileName, File folder) throws IOException{
  OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder, filename));
  try{
    getDbxClient().getFile(fileName, null, outputStream );
  }catch(IOException e){
    throw e;
  }catch(DbxException u){
    throw new IOException(u.getCause());
  }finally {
    outputstream.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need hierarchically of class for my app in JEE. I need that OutputStream arrive to Dropbox class and the dropbox class arrive to test class with the container of OutputStream. 
Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'll have to `flush` (see corresponding method) the outputsteam to your file (and close it). The Dropbox API is dealing with OutputStream, but certainly do not care that you want to write a file.

you can have a look to thee following [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/).

Comment: I have used the fuction Flush in all  the levels, but the File is still empty.

Comment: do you already have a look to the tutoriel at https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/java ?

Comment: Yes, the fuction of Dropbox operate nice. I am using  this Dropbox fuction in my app for other processes. Thanks for your interest